# converting MB into TB perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the size of a file in megabytes using Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511785/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-megabytes-using-perl)

I tried some ways to convert MB into TB in perl, but value does not match in perl output and online converter.

whats the best formula to convert the above.

Comment: You need to specify whether it's binary or SI prefixes. The size of the difference using binary prefixes (2^20) is ~4.8% larger than that of SI prefixes (1000^2).

Comment: Perhaps you want to see [How do I get the size of a file in megabytes using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511785/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-megabytes-using-perl)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want any digits after the decimal, you can just shift to the right by 20 bits:

```
perl -e 'print 202220394 >> 20;'
```

gives `192`.  Whereas 202 220 394 megabytes = 192.852396 terabytes.

If you want the decimals, divide by 2^20:

```
perl -e 'print 202220394 / (1 << 20);'
```

gives `192.852396011353`.

Comment: Dave,is there any difference in formula for Processor/Virtual Storage vs Disk Storage ? to convert MB into TB ?

Comment: Sure. The disk storage people have coopted the "MB" type prefix such that M means 1,000,000 or 10^6.  But before that, M meant 2^20 which is slightly more than one million.  Some have taken to using "MiB" for "mebibyte" to mean this 2^20 value.  Unfortuantely, it's not clear by just looking at a number, but as you hint you can usually assume that disk storage on a package is 10^6 and everything inside a computer is 2^20.  TiB is 2^40 vs. 10^12 so you can see the different conversions between MiB/TiB = 2^20/2^40 vs MB/TB = 10^6/10^12.