# get human friendly file size from shell in unix-like environments [portability]

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm using the following to get human friendly file sizes from the shell.

```
ls -hl /path/to/file | awk '{print $5}'
```

It works well in Mac OSX with bash. I'm not sure if its truly portable, or if there is a standard portable way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Instead of parsing `ls`, check your `stat` man page.

Comment: But for portability, you'll want to use a general purpose language that runs identically on multiple platforms. For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/512645/7552

Comment: How portable are you looking for?  POSIX?  SUS?  Embedded systems running busybox?

Comment: If you do `stat -c %s /path/to/file` gets you the size in bytes. But not in human friendly mode.

Comment: just posix, and human friendly is the goal, although i guess i can use stat and divide by 1024*N

Comment: `wc -c` will portably get you the file size in bytes, but you need to convert to kb, mb, etc yourself.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27828585/816536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most implementations of [`du(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) accept the `-h` flag, which causes it to print the disk usage of the file, or files, specified.  The difference between disk usage and file size in normally innocuous, rounding up to the nearest file-system block.

The `-h` flag, though widely supported, is an extension.  For maximum portability unit conversion would have to be done manually an [pointed out by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253450/get-human-friendly-file-size-from-shell-in-unix-like-environments-portability/39504243#comment65845830_39253450).

[*BSD](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/du.1), [Illumos](https://illumos.org/man/1/du), [BusyBox](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/du.c#n39), and [GNU CoreUtils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation) all support the `-h` flag.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want strict POSIX compatibility then you must do as is suggested in [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828838/816536), and do your own computation (e.g. in `awk` too) to calculate the desired "human-friendly" value.